# ASP.NET Regular Expresion don't match when update value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I have an ASP.NET page with many textboxes where it is possible to write values in Currency format.
When the user writes a value, I execute a javascript function that formats the numbers by adding the Euro symbol and the dot "." that separate the thousands and comma "," for decimals.
To perform the formatting I execute the following function in javascript

```
$(function () {
    $("#text1").blur(function () {
        $(this).formatCurrency();
    });
});
```

this function is used to format even negative numbers correctly, I can have only two results

- positive number € 1.000,00
- negative number (€ 1.000,00)

The negative number is enclosed in parentheses

The textbox has the following regularexpresion:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="text1" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegEx1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RangeValidator"
 ValidationExpression="^(-?\$?([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*|[1-9]\d*|0|)(.\d{1,2})?|\(\$?([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*|[1-9]\d*|0|)(.\d{1,2})?\))$"
ValidationGroup="Group2" CssClass="failureNotification" ControlToValidate="text1"
Display="Dynamic">L'Importo non è corretto</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

This Regular Expresion work well if I write first time a value, but if I update the value don't match.
Example
-I write 1000
-java format value to € 1.000,00
-I change the number 1 to 2
-€ 2.000,00
-I get error from regular expresion, don't match

If I delete all value and write 2000 it work well.

Is it possible that there are problems using the regulaexpresion when using the blur function in javascript?

Thanks for your help

**SOLUTION:**

I've found the problem!
The RegularExpresion takes effect before formatting by javascript is performed.
I changed the regularexpresion and now everything works fine.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RangeValidator"
ValidationExpression="^\-?\(?\€? ?(\d{1,3}[.](\d{3}[.])*\d{3}|\d+)([,]\d{1,2})?\)?$"
ValidationGroup="Group2" CssClass="failureNotification" ControlToValidate="b1crediti_soci_dovuti" Diplay="Dynamic">L'Importo non è corretto</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I hope this post help someone! ;)

Comment: Where is the connection to Java?

Comment: sorry, I've used javascript

Answer (score 1):

Even provided that you are using a view model for your view, there is a specific attribute for regular expression...

```
[RegularExpression($"^(-?\$?([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*|[1-9]\d*|0|)(.\d{1,2})?|\(\$?([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*|[1-9]\d*|0|)(.\d{1,2})?\))$")]
public string property { get; set; }
```

This way of using regular expression for your view pieces of data, will always work for your asp.net core web projects.